# How can I show data from 2 tables using AJAX and Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, search

I've created Live Search using AJAX, where users can search for jobs and where it's returning data from my `employer_profiles` table, specifically 2 columns, `company_name` and `company_address`. I have a second table called `job_posts` with 2 columns `job_title` and `job_description`. This is where the Employer who is logged in can create jobs for their company, when they are looking to hire someone. Of course there is a relationship here, both tables have a user_id column.

I want to display in my table 3 columns, `company_name` and `company_address` from `employer_profiles` table and `job_title` from the `job_posts` table.

Is there a JOIN would help? If yes how can I do this exactly?
Here is the code that I have that is fetching only from the `employer_profiles` table.

AdminJobSeekerSearchController.php:

```
public function action(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $output = '';

        $query = $request->get('query');
        if($query != ''){
            $data = DB::table('employer_profiles')
                ->where('company_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('company_address', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->get();
        }else{
            $data = DB::table('employer_profiles')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get();
        }

        $total_row = $data->count();

        if($total_row > 0){
            foreach($data as $row){
                $output .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row->company_name.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row->company_address.'</td>
                    <td><a type="button" href="/admin/job-seeker/search/employer/'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }
        }else{
            $output = '
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }
        $data = array(
            'table_data' => $output,
            'total_data' => $total_row
        );
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

index.blade:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')

    @if (session('send-profile'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('account') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Topbar Search -->
            <form class="navbar-search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control bg-lightblue border-0 small text-white border-dark" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">
                            <i class="fas fa-cannabis"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form><br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <table class="table table-hover table-responsive-sm">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr class="align-items-center"><th colspan="4" style="text-align: center;"><h5><strong>Total Results: <span id="total_records"></span></strong></h5></th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Immediate Contact</th>
                    <th scope="col">Address</th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>



                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

    </div>

    {{-- Show Pagination --}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center">

            {{$employerProfiles->render()}}

        </div>
    </div>

@stop

@push('scripts')
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            fetch_customer_data();

            function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
            {

                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('admin.job.seeker.search.action') }}",
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: {query:query},
                    dataType:'json',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
                        $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
                    }
                })

            }

            $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
                var query = $(this).val();
                fetch_customer_data(query);
            })

        });

    </script>
@endpush
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/admin/job-seeker/search/action', 'AdminJobSeekerSearchController@action')->name('admin.job.seeker.search.action')->middleware('verified');
```

Comment: Is this a real world project or are you just learning?

Comment: Real world. I’m building a ‘job search’ web app for a client with two types of users, job seekers and employers.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I couldn’t get it to display. I created a relationship in the EmployerProfile model called jobposts, and then tried to display it in the table for each loop like this: $row->jobposts()->job_title but that didn’t work.

Comment: Should be `$row->jobposts->job_title`, not `jobposts()` when calling the relationship. Read the docs. Why not use a solution that already exists instead of reinventing the wheel? Since you're already using JQuery, why not pull in DataTables?

Comment: I really just wanted to practice AJAX. I found this solution on YouTube. It so hard to know what is still popular in this field. I’ll look into it.

Comment: p.s. ```$row->jobposts->job_title``` did not work. error is ```"message": "Undefined property: stdClass::$jobposts"```

Comment: It is difficult to suggest what joins you should do when you don't tell us what the tables look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, this gives you enough to understand how to do it.

Note: your controller is trying to output json but your output string is html.

Assuming these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `employer_profiles` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `company_address` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE `job_posts` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employer_profile_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Here is some data

```
INSERT INTO `employer_profiles` (`id`, `company_name`, `company_address`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
(1, 'Bolay', '123 main street', '2020-03-29 07:18:30', '2020-03-29 07:18:30'),
(2, 'Barones Pizza', '345 Sample road', '2020-03-29 07:18:56', '2020-03-29 07:18:56'),
(3, 'Sigma Electronics', '34 Yamato Road', '2020-03-29 07:23:21', '2020-03-29 07:23:21');
```

Jobs:

```
INSERT INTO `job_posts` (`id`, `employer_profile_id`, `description`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'Cashier', '2020-03-29 07:20:18', '2020-03-29 07:20:23'),
(2, 1, 'Food prep', '2020-03-29 07:20:35', '2020-03-29 07:20:35'),
(3, 2, 'Chef', '2020-03-29 07:23:41', '2020-03-29 07:23:41'),
(4, 3, 'QA engineer', '2020-03-29 07:24:00', '2020-03-29 07:24:00');
```

Typical code using the DB facade:

```
$data = DB::table('employer_profiles')
        ->join('job_posts', 'job_posts.employer_profile_id', '=', 'employer_profiles.id')
        ->get();
    foreach($data as $row){
        echo json_encode($row) . "\n";
    }
```

Using eloquent

EmployerProfile.php

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EmployerProfile extends Model
{
    public function jobposts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\JobPost');
    }
}
```

JobPost.php

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JobPost extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Then, in general you can use this code. This particular code snippet was run in a Laravel Command. You can think of it as code that you could use anywhere.

```
use App\JobPost;
use App\EmployerProfile;

    $all = EmployerProfile::all();
    foreach($all as $emp) {
        $this->line($emp->company_name);
        foreach($emp->jobposts as $post) {
            $this->line('   ' . $post->description);
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\EmployerProfile;

class EmployerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $all = EmployerProfile::all();
        $output = [];
        foreach($all as $emp) {
            foreach($emp->jobposts as $post) {
                $output[] = [
                    'company_name' => $emp->company_name,
                    'company_address' => $emp->company_address,
                    'description' => $post->description
                ];
            }
        }
        // output json
        return response()->json($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 questions. 1) I thought when creating a relationship you would need to put in JobPost.php model this as well?
```
public function employerprofile(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\EmployerProfile');

    }
```

2) what is 'line' in this code?
```
use App\JobPost;
use App\EmployerProfile;

    $all = EmployerProfile::all();
    foreach($all as $emp) {
        $this->line($emp->company_name);
        foreach($emp->jobposts as $post) {
            $this->line('   ' . $post->description);
        }
    }
```

Comment: also where does this code go in which controller?
```
use App\JobPost;
use App\EmployerProfile;

    $all = EmployerProfile::all();
    foreach($all as $emp) {
        $this->line($emp->company_name);
        foreach($emp->jobposts as $post) {
            $this->line('   ' . $post->description);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Line` is a function provided for Laravel commands on the command line. All it does it output like echo. You can ignore it.

Comment: You do not have to define both sides of the join. You can only define one side if that is all you are going to use.

Comment: I would recommend that you look at laracasts.com for training and tutorials.